# Confirmation before deleting plugin options via uninstall.php

Tags: options

I'm creating a WordPress plugin and have the uninstall.php file ready. It deletes the options used by the plugin on deletion. What I'd like to do is to popup a dialog box asking whether to delete or keep these options when the user decides to delete the plugin. How can I do this?

```
<?php
// If uninstall not called from WordPress exit
if( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) )
exit ();
// Delete option from options table
delete_option( 'my_options' );
//
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a JavaScript alert to do what you're asking, but the only way I can think of doing it would likely be a fair chunk of unnecessary added complexity.

I've written a small PHP script using the code from your example. If you have any difficulty amending it for your purposes, please don't hesitate to let me know.

```
<?php 
    // die if not uninstalling
    if( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) )
        exit ();

    // if the "act" variable hasn't been set, display a form
    if (!isset($_GET["act"])) {
?>
    <p>Would you like to keep the options configured by this plugin?</p>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>">
        <select name="act">
            <option>Select choice..</option>
            <option value="keep">Keep options</option>
            <option value="delete">Delete options</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
<?php
    } else {
        // if the "act" variable has been set, see if the user wants to delete the options..
        if ($_GET["act"] == "delete") {
            delete_option( 'my_options' );
            echo "Options deleted; uninstallation successful.";
            return;
        } else {
            // .. or keep them
            echo "Options kept; uninstallation successful.";
            return;
        }
    }
?>
```

** EDIT: PREFERENCE ROUTE **

OK, according to [this post](http://old.nabble.com/register_uninstall_hook-VS-uninstall.php-td28488639.html), apparently you shouldn't / can't use much more PHP in `uninstall.php` than the basic deleting of options etc.

As such, my advice would be this: create an option in your plugin settings which says "keep settings on deletion" or similar (called "DELETE_OPTIONS" in my example). Then use the following code in your `uninstall.php`:

```
<?php 
    $options = get_option('MY_PLUGIN_OPTIONS');

    if ( true === $options['DELETE_OPTIONS'] ) {
        delete_option('MY_PLUGIN_OPTIONS');
    }
?>
```

Regards,
Duncan

Comment: I've tried this out but I don't get the confirmation screen. I've attached the test plugin I'm using to try it out, http://www.2shared.com/file/LcfDix_X/test-plugin.html

Comment: Hi drtanz. I've updated my post.

Comment: The plugin settings option is the best way to go. I add a check box option to all plugins I create.

Comment: Aye it's not as good as a JavaScript alert, but it'll do the job :) Thanks for accept.

Comment: Just to think about this... What would be the default value of "$options['DELETE_OPTIONS']" to start with? its not user friendly at all. Un-install process should ask user to make that choice at the point and not in admin options.